# Can we solve Fractional Knapsack Problem by DP?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I know the Greedy approach is the best solution, but I'm so curious.

here is some of my code ...

```
def fractional_knapsack_dp2(): 
global resValue

# 각 size W를 넘지 않는 상태에서, i개의 아이템을 담은 상태에서 최대 profit을 담는 배열 
P = [ [0 for x in range(W+1)] for x in range(n+1)] # [n+1][W+1] 0으로 초기화 

for i in range(n+1):
    currWeight = 0
    for w in range(W+1):
        if i==0 or w==0: # 0행 또는 0열은 skip 
            P[i][w] = 0;

        elif weights[i-1] <= w:
            currWeight = weights[i-1]
            P[i][w] = max( values[i-1] + P[i-1][w - weights[i-1]], P[i-1][w] )

        else:
            # weight 1 단위로 설정  ... dksl d어케함 ;;
            frac = 1 / weights[i-1]
            if ( frac*values[i-1] + P[i-1][w - 1] > P[i-1][w] ) :
                P[i][w] = P[i-1][w-1]
                for k in range(w - currWeight) :
                    currWeight += 1
                    P[i][w] += frac*values[i-1]
            else : 
                P[i][w] = P[i-1][w]

resValue = P[n][W]
```

I don't know how can I solve the problem.

Should I make another recurrence relation or array?

I didn't learn about Dynamic Programming yet.

Comment: What is the issue with the current approach you've added to the question?

Comment: I can't get an accurate answer. Here is my full code git link. https://github.com/isdiscodead/2022_KUS/blob/master/Spring/ComputationalThinking/fractional_knapsack.py